# How the multidimensional array works?

Tags: c, arrays

In this program an array has 3 sizes. First size refers to row, second refers to column, but what the third do? I have another question, array refers `%s` to print.But in this program array printed by `%d`.Since array assign to `x` value. Which is `int` data type, but we print array. So how it would be `%d`?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char array[3][3][3];
    int i,j,k;

    int x = 1;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<3; j++){
           for(k=0; k<3; k++){
                array[i][j][k] = x;
                printf("%d\n", array[i][j][k]);
                x++;
           }

        }

    }
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Shortest answer: third one is an index of matrices of dimension `[3][3]`. BTW tons of info on the web....[c 3D array](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c+3d+array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char[3]` filled with ones would look like:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

`char[3][3]` filled with ones would look like:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+
```

`char[3][3][3]` filled with ones would be three above square arrays one over one. There will be a cube.

[image]

On the above picture, each small cube will represent single cell so there are 27 cells in total.

I'm glad you didn't ask about `char[3][3][3][3]`.

Comment: My dear friend thank you for your answer.I know char[3] would be assign 3 character one by one.But what is the char[3][3][3] means?Is it means 9 character one by one.I am a new learner.                                                                             Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

To start with the second question first, you have an array of arrays of arrays of (small) *integers*. How do you print an *integer* using `printf`? You (can) use the `"%d"` format. You are confused (I guess) because strings (which are printed with `"%s"`) are arrays of characters. But you are not printing an array, you are printing individual `int` values.

As for the first question, part of the answer is in the above paragraph. You have an array of three arrays of three arrays of three (small) integers. Rows and columns are just labels, and for a "3d" array they don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question of the array[3][3][3], this is a 3 dimension table. You can think of it as three 2-dimension tables.
table 0: 3x3
table 1: 3x3
table 2: 3x3

Rows and Columns are descriptions we use to better understand the concept of 2 dimension elements. The array can have more dimensions - if it helps you, you can think of it as list of ( list(of list(..)))

Regarding the char question and the integer representation, chars and ints can be used in the same way in C. chars are essentially ASCII characters represented by the character's index in the ASCII table. ie. 'a' is 97.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about book. A single line on a page of the book is a 1d array. The whole page is a 2d array. The whole book is a 3d array. Let's assume, the book is in a box, then the box represents a 4d array. A set of boxes is a 5d array. So, you can think more of this. So, We will represent the first element of the first page of the first book of the first box as [0][0][0][0][0].

```
%s - Take the next argument and print it as a string
%d - Take the next argument and print it as an int
```

Here, your array elements are integer. Your code prints the array element one by one.

Answer (score -1):

`%d` is for decimal, `%s`is for string.
Here's a representation of a 3D array, the third dimension is the "depth" or in other words, the content of row i and column j (which in a 2d array would be an element but in a 3D array is an array)

```
int myFirst3DArray [3][4][2] = 
{
  {{10,11},{12,13},{14,15},{16,17}},
  {{18,19},{20,21},{22,23},{24,25}},
  {{26,27},{28,29},{30,31},{32,33}}
};
```

Comment: I posted a picture to show the content of the array which I cant align using code.

Comment: Perhaps learn the basics of using the site before announcing what is and is not possible. If posting as code did not allow the indentation of code then it wouldn't be much use at all. Again, as you have been asked, please post code not pictures of code.